# Environemnt variables changes are not reflecting while using gitlab-ci

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab-ci & my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like

`variables:
  DASHBOARD_RESET_ROUTE: '/#/reset-password'
  DEFAULT_LOCATION_TYPE: 'P'`

This was deployed successfully but when I changed the value of `DEFAULT_LOCATION_TYPE` to some other text.

The console logs are still showing the old values

Then, even after removing the whole variable from both .yml file & gitlab.com secret variables. The console.logs still print the old values.

Output at gitlab.com UI is:

`Running with gitlab-runner 10.1.0 (c1ebf97h)
  on Test - ip-172-31-12-234 (6d0vb950)
Using Shell executor...
Running on ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX...
Fetching changes...
Removing node_modules/
HEAD is now at fff6491 wip
Checking out fff64913 as feat/ci-cd...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
$ npm install`

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So reason was using `shell` as an executor, That was the reason the environment variables are not reloaded again.

Then I reconfigured with `docker` as an executor & it's working fine.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is the solution and how you changed the executor? I have a more or less similar problem.